# Reinstalling Windows Vista 64 Bit

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I really like Ubuntu, but my family is used to Windows and I would like to dual boot it but accidentally did a full install and now I just have Ubuntu.

Is there any way to me to get back Windows Vista 64 bit?

Comment: This should be migrated to SU, because it is a question about Windows and Data-Recovery, not directly related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll need to reinstall - when you do I suggest you follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) so you can keep the Ubuntu installation and dual boot the operating systems together.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I will save this on my bookmarks right away.

Comment: Quick question Mark, I just found some backup discs that I had (5 discs total) how would I know if that's the backup discs I need or are they just backup files that are only useful when I get the actual OS backup discs? I'm really new at this so I don't wanna do something now and regret it later had I not asked.

Comment: Did you make recovery discs when you first got the PC? I'm uncertain as to whether they will work as you have no NTFS partition that they would reference. You could try and 'shrink' the Ubuntu partition so that you could try a recovery but I've never done it so I can't really tell.

Comment: Yes, I made the recovery discs as soon as I started using my PC Mark. Everytime I load the disc into my PC, a file called "UDF Volume" shows up on my desktop. When I go to my computer, and click the disc, it shows my PC files, autorun.inf, MediaID.bin and restore.ico. I used the HP Easy Backup program I don't know if that helps narrow it down.

Comment: Nevermind Mark. I had to dig around and just found out that it only backs up files and programs and not OS. Good thing is I can order the recovery discs so yay.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the whole hard disk for Ubuntu, NTFS partition you had for windows got reformatted as a Linux partition. Then you cannot get back Windows Vista using usual methods.

I am not sure if any data recovery tool works or not.

To confirm if you still have windows vista partitions remaining, 
Open a terminal (Application -> accessories) and issue the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you see NTFS as a value for any line entry in last coloumn, that is your windows partition. But if you are only seeing Linux there, you are out of luck.

eg:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2              26       16032   128564279+   7  HPFS/NTFS   <-- Windows
/dev/sda6           16032       24175    65413120   83  Linux    <--Linux
```

Comment: You're right. The only thing that is coming up under system is Linux. Thank you Jamess for the help.

Comment: Data recovery tools should not work in this case.  The operating system is typically located at the front of the drive.  This would almost surely have been overwritten by the necessary ubuntu files.  A recovery partition is usually at the back end of the disk.  With many modern file systems, some data is stored at the end of the partition as well.  This would most likely have overwritten something in the recovery partition.  No dice on recovery.  Need to purchase install media.

Comment: Thank you aking1012. Maybe I shouldn't have been such an idiot and just installed it alongside Windows, but you learn from your mistakes. At least I got to know how great Ubuntu is so at least something good came from it.